# How much time to wait for an action on my question after offering a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've offered my first bounty on [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450791/oracle-bi-publisher-different-behaviour-between-10g-and-11g), and I'm not sure how long I should wait to notice a movement or at least increased number of views.

It's been about an hour and only one new user read my question after that!

Is that normal, or am I rushing things?

Comment: You're rushing things. Relax a bit, and give it time. Your bounty lasts 7 days, if you don't manually award it early. For your best bet, wait the 7 days for answers, and award your bounty to the most helpful answer in the grace period.

Comment: This meta post may help your question get more views.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion,  Not much actually, only 4 new views

Comment: You should be aware that the planet rotates about its axis and that contributors need to sleep, work etc. in different time-zones.  24 hours is a good time to wait before checking.

Comment: Geeks don't sleep my friend :) post any question, someone will pop up and give you a great answer, especially if it was on a technology, not an application like in my case ;)

Comment: I've never known bounties to be particularly effective in attracting attention (or good answers).  The answers you do attract are often of such poor quality that it hurts to think that your bounty (or at least half of it) must be awarded to one of them.

Comment: @HotLicks, this is part of the risk, if your question wasnt receiving a good attention, and it is a good question, it worth to spend some reputation on it

Comment: @simsim - Except that it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently [362 featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) on Stack Overflow, and yours is one of the newest. You should start to see more views as your question moves to the front of that list, which will be near the end of the bounty period. Before then, you should see some increased traffic from users who hunt bounties in the SQL tag.

Comment: I've red the help regarding adding a bounty, didn't notice a tip about where it will be placed among the other bounty offering questions, but I will wait of course, thanks